# Why do some questions have a blue tint on the iOS app?

Tags: discussion, questions

On some questions, there is a blue tint in the background. What does it mean?

[image: Screenshot]

Some reasons I've eliminated due to inconsistency:

- Reputation of asker
- On Hold
- Unanswered

Comment: I actually don't see the blue tint in your screenshot, but I'm guessing this is a "favorite tags" feature. Where the tags you've marked as your favorite have a different background color in the list of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely the 'Favorite Tag' feature in action. Similar to the main site:

[image]

Tags you have marked as favorite will show up with a yellow background. In the case of the iOS app, the theme is slightly different, so they show up with a blue tint.